# Cannot compile a testcase file on Lion says undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: macos, compilation, gcc

I have a simple `testcase.cpp` file with 2 .data files under my test folder. When I try to compile the test on OS X Lion, I get an error message that says:

```
g++ -o testcase testcase.cpp
```

However it does not compile and complains:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Has someone faced this error? Can you tell me if I need to set some flag or something while compiling?

Update: this is a graphics test case, so it includes glut. I tried to add `-lglut` to the command line, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer: you need to add "-framework OpenGL -framework GLUT" to the command line.

Comment: Since this fixed it for you, mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to your answer.